# iOS8: How to load xib from Dynamic Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am using Cocoapods pre-release 0.36 to build and deploy a private *dynamic framework* into an app bundle.  I am using the resources attribute to copy xibs, and they show up in the app bundle.

```
s.subspec 'Views' do |ss|
    ...
    ss.resources = ['All/My/Folders/**/*.{xib,png}']
    ...
```

I am trying to load reusable controls from the xibs like this:

`NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyXib", owner:loader, options:nil)`

but this is failing as it cannot find the xib in my embedded sub framework.  The actual xib (nib) paths follow the pattern:'

`./Frameworks/MyPrivateFramework.framework/MyXib.nib`

My question is, is there a simple, code agnostic way of loading the xib that will work when packaged in an iOS 8 framework - or do I have to explicitly hardcode in the above path?  The above loading code worked until I think the dynamic framework change.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From this post here:

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2015/01/04/cocoapods-and-frameworks/

I arrived at the agnostic solution of getting the framework bundle from a class within, ie:

```
NSBundle(forClass: ClassInFramework.self)
```

and then loading the xib from that:

```
NSBundle(forClass: ClassInFramework.self)
    .loadNibNamed("ClassInFramework", owner:loader, options:nil)
```

and that worked.